# JavaScript Slider Selecting Wrong Section

Tags: javascript, jquery

A client's website (Drupal) has a simple Javascript slider that shows employees by department. Slider is set to show arrows only when list items in the section are > 4. Arrows are set to slide employees/section list items left or right when they are clicked by adjusting the margin-left. Slider was counting items of next section and showing arrows at incorrect times. This meant that users could never see all of the employees in the Sales department, as arrows weren't showing and there are 7 list items.

I added a .prev() to the itemCount variable in the  checkSectionSize function, but now the arrows aren't triggering a change in margin-left. They were before my tweak. So, now arrows are showing when viewing sales department, but they are useless.

A console.log is showing that they are grabbing the sectionWidth of the previous section. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I inherited this slider and don't have any contact with previous web master.

```
(function($) {
    Shadowbox.init();
    $('.video-link').attr('rel', 'shadowbox');
    $('.external').attr('target', '_blank');

    (function () {
        var $teamSlider      = $('.team-slider'),
            $sectionNav      = $teamSlider.find('.sections li'),
            $sectionNavItems = $sectionNav.find('a'),
            $nextButton      = $teamSlider.find('.arrow-next'),
            $previousButton  = $teamSlider.find('.arrow-back'),
            $teamWrapper     = $teamSlider.find('.teams'),
            $teams           = $teamWrapper.find('ul'),
            $item            = $teams.find('li'),
            $slider          = $teamSlider.find('.slider'),
            sectionWidth     = $teamSlider.width(),
            frameWidth       = $slider.width(),
            itemWidth        = $slider.width() / 4,
            itemHeight       = $item.height(),
            currentSection   = 1;

            function changeSection(event) {
                  var $this = $(this),
                      index = +$this.attr('href').substr(1);
                      newY  = -itemHeight * (index - 1),
                      newX  = 0,
                      currentSection = index;

                  $sectionNav.removeClass('active');
                  $this.parent().addClass('active');

                  moveTeamWrapper(newX, newY);
                  checkSectionSize($teams.eq(currentSection));
                  return false;
                }

                function moveTeamWrapper (x, y) {
  var properties = {
        'margin-top': y + 'px',
        'margin-left': x + 'px'
      },
      options = {
        duration: 300,
        easing: 'swing'
      };

  $teamWrapper.animate(properties, options);
}

function previousClick (event) {
  var $this          = $(this),
      $section       = $teams.eq(currentSection),
      itemCount      = $section.find('li').length,
      sectionWidth   = $section.width(),
      offset         = +$teamWrapper.css('margin-left').replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/, '');

  if (offset < 0) {
    moveTeamWrapper('+=' + itemWidth, -itemHeight * (currentSection - 1));
  }

  return false;
}

function nextClick (event) {
  var $this          = $(this),
      $section       = $teams.eq(currentSection),
      itemCount      = $section.find('li').length,
      sectionWidth   = $section.width(),
      offset         = +$teamWrapper.css('margin-left').replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/, '');

  if (sectionWidth - itemWidth + offset >= frameWidth) {
    moveTeamWrapper('-=' + itemWidth, -itemHeight * (currentSection - 1));
  }

  return false;
}

function hideArrows() {
  $previousButton.fadeOut();
  $nextButton.fadeOut();
}

function showArrows() {
  $previousButton.fadeIn();
  $nextButton.fadeIn();
}

function checkSectionSize(item) {
  var $item = $(item),
  itemCount = $item.prev().find('li').length;


  if (! $.browser.msie) {
    if (itemCount > 4) {
      console.log("Arrows");
      console.log(itemCount);
      console.log("Section is " +currentSection);
      showArrows();
    } else {
      hideArrows();
      console.log(itemCount);
      console.log("Section is " + currentSection);
    }
  }
}

frameWidth = sectionWidth - $nextButton.width() - $previousButton.width();
itemWidth = frameWidth / 4;
$slider.css('width', frameWidth);

$teams.each(function () {
   var $item = $(this),
       $items = $item.find('li'),
       itemCount = $items.length;

  $items.width(itemWidth);

  if (itemWidth * itemCount > frameWidth ) {
    $item.width(itemWidth * itemCount);
  }
});

$sectionNavItems.live('click', changeSection);
$nextButton.live('click', nextClick);
$previousButton.live('click', previousClick);

$sectionNavItems.first().trigger('click');
```

} ());

Comment: @MrsLaffitte do you have any HTML and maybe some CSS to go along with that jQuery?